# EF Core : transaction rollback doesn't work, data is still commited

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        // logic
        _context.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Commit();
     } 
     catch 
     { 
         transaction.Rollback(); 
     }
}
```

When an error occurs in the `//logic` section of the code, it jumps to `transaction.rollback()`, however, the data is still committed to the MySQL database.

For info, in the `//logic` section of the code, I perform some operations on the context, like `Remove`, `Add`, `Update`, `SaveChanges`

//EDIT 1:
It seems that the outer context.SaveChanges is commiting the changes that have been already rollbacked.

```
public void AddUser() {
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        // logic
        _context.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Commit();
     } 
     catch 
     { 
         transaction.Rollback(); 
         throw;
     }
}
}


public void Init(){

 try {
   AddUser();
 } catch(Exception e) {
   _context.Logs.Add(new Log(e.Message));
   _context.SaveChanges();  // <-------- this commits changes rollbacked from the AddUser()
 }

}
```

Comment: I'm using EF Core for the operations and everything is inside the try catch context that you see above.

Comment: You might want to add a Savepoint to revert back to when failing. Prior to executing the logic transaction.CreateSavepoint("ReturnToThis"); and utilising this in your catch transaction.RollbackToSavepoint("ReturnToThis");.

Comment: Which MySql provider do you use? Pomelo or official?

Comment: This one https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.22/

Comment: Try [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/3.2.7), maybe it works more correctly than official.

Comment: You should show the code in `// logic`. Seeing the code, nothing should be committed. Is there some async code involved?

Comment: @Gert Arnold. I finally found why. In the outer scope of the code you see in my thread, there is a try catch with some logging mechanism in the catch where it calls a context.SaveChanges(). It seems that the changes are still in the context even after RollBack, so if I do a save changes, it will commit them.  How to make sure this is not happening ?

Comment: Create a separate context class for logging and use it completely separately from application code so that you can always log anything even when a transaction fails (which in effect you already do now, except that now too much is saved). Or use a logging framework like NLog or SeriLog.

Comment: Yes, rolling back a transaction does not discard changes that the DbContext is tracking. The DbContext is considered "poisoned". For EF Core you can use `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();` to flush all pending tracked changes.  Ideally though for logging I generally recommend using a bounded DbContext that only cares about logging entities separate from the app DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use it the right way. You have to begin a transaction.

```
try
{
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // logic
        _context.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Commit();   
    }
} 
catch 
{ 
    // you do not need to rollback. When it gets out of the block it rollbacks automatically
}
```

Comment: OP's code should also rollback the transaction, even without an explicit rollback statement. It's not "wrong" as you suggest.